# What is the role of RAGEs?

Tags: senescence

According to articles I read, AGEs (advanced glycation end products) activate RAGEs (receptors for AGEs). This activation increases the ROS (reactive oxygen species) levels in the cells.

[image: Reactive Oxygen Species-Regulated Signaling Pathways in Diabetic Nephropathy]

- [2003 - Reactive Oxygen Species-Regulated Signaling Pathways in Diabetic Nephropathy](http://jasn.asnjournals.org/content/14/suppl_3/S241/F3.expansion)

Free radicals can cause damage in cells, which is definitely not good. What do you think, what is the role of RAGEs, which is more important than cellular damage?